# Multilingual website - rewrite folder name in URL depending on the language

Tags: .htaccess

I'm stuck in rewriting a url. The context is :

- my website is physically stored under a subfolder www/blog-voyage/ : (which means"travel blog" in french).
- I have a rule redirecting www.example.com to www.example.com/blog-voyage/

I have a multilingual website, meaning :

- french post : www.example.com/blog-voyage/my-article-name
- english post : www.example.com/blog-voyage/en/my-article-name

As you can see, I still have /blog-voyage/ in the english url.

Do you have any idea how I could "translate" /blog-voyage/ to /travel-blog/ only for the english url please, keeping in mind /blog-voyage/ is a real folder while the translation /travel-blog/ is just a translation of the words and there is no folder /travel-blog/.

Thanks a lot,
Jérémy

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
RewriteRule ^blog-voyage/$ /travel-blog/ [L]
```

ps. I'm English speaker I know voyage means travel ;)

Comment: Thanks, but this will redirect ALL my pages, no ? Not only my english pages ?

Answer (score 0):

Am I right saying the previous answer will redirect everything and not only my english pages ?